# Can Greater Gift of Consumption redirect a coup de grace?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, saving-throw, witch

The hexes [Gift of Consumption](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/gift-of-consumption-su/) and [Greater Gift of Consumption](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/greater-gift-of-consumption-su/) are thematically fascinating, allowing you to share and redirect enemy spells and poisons to nearby enemies (or allies!). Greater Gift of Consumption reads in part:

> If the witch ever fails a Fortitude save or intentionally exposes herself to an effect that requires a Fortitude save, such as by ingesting a poison, she can redirect that effect to affect only the hexed creature, though the hexed creature can still attempt a saving throw to resist the effects.

If you have an ally tie you up, becoming [helpless](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#helpless), an ally (or your familiar, or an enemy) can Coup de Grace you as a full-round action with a scythe, dealing easily 20 damage and forcing a DC 30 Fortitude save to not instantly die. I don't think any of this so far is in question.

However, can a witch with the hexes Gift of Consumption and Greater Gift of Consumption redirect the DC 30 Fortitude save to an enemy, automatically surviving (other than the 20 damage) while likely slaying the enemy as well?

I believe this works, but I have my doubts. For one, this makes Greater Gift of Consumption practically immunity to Fortitude saves. If there's a nearby enemy (who you haven't already used this on), you can ignore the first failed Fortitude save each turn as an immediate action.

Bonus: for a fast version of the combo, can the witch use [Slumber](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-slumber-su/) to become helpless as a standard action, or does sleeping prevent immediate actions right after being rudely awoken by a scythe?

Comment: In terms of the bonus question: I think it's more a question of timing. What happens first: you waking up because you got hit by a scythe so you can do the immediate action before the Fort save, or you waking up and doing the Fort save because that's tied to the effect of a scythe attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Only enemies can coup-de-grace you

The [helpless](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Helpless) condition says:

> As a full-round action, **an enemy** can use a melee weapon to deliver a coup de grace to a helpless foe

[Enemy is not a defined game term](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pzge?What-is-an-enemy), and what counts as an enemy is tricky, but I think it is safe to say that your ally who is helping you to pull this off is not an enemy.

It‘s of course another question why only enemies should be able to coup-de-grace helpless creatures, because technically anyone who'd like to do it should be able to - for example a friend who wants to kill you for mercy before some nefarious effect transforms you to an horrible undead abomination that will suffer for eternity. But if you have concerns about abusing Greater Gift of Consumption this way, it's a rules-as-written way to address this.

Comment: That's a bit disappointing, but you're right. On the plus side, the more I experiment with this combo the more it feels like a witch's ritual out of folklore. "You must bind yourself with three cords, and inveigle a mortal enemy to take your life; in the killing blow his heart shall stop, not your own." Suggestion is presumably the best method, or some kind of hostile summoning.